# Pseudo-Code 2 Array : 1 unsorted 1 for index min position

Tags: arrays, indexing, pseudocode, sorting

I want access orderly to the array elements (a: array [1 .. N] of int) without changing the arrangement. The idea is to use a table b: array [1 .. N] of nat containing (sequentially) the indexes of the elements according to the desired order, so that: a[b[i]] ≤ a[b[i + 1 ]] for 1 ≤ i < N. For example, for 
a = [4,7,1,3,9] table is b = [3,4,1,2,5].

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do exactly.
You're posting an unclear pseudo-code and asking for another one.

Comment: I change my question in order to make it clear. thanks.